# How does selenium webdriver (source code) gets the text from the alert or confirm window for firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium-webdriver, watin

How does selenium webdriver (source code) gets the text from the alert or confirm window for firefox?

First to clear: I don't want the way of using selenium webdriver to work with alerts and get text and dismiss them.

Actually, I am just interested in getting the text of a JavaScript Alert or Confirm dialog which appears in Firefox. I want to implement the same for WatiN with MozRepl or any C# API which cab get the text of the Alert. I am interested in the text or say message given by the alert or confirm and not the title/caption of alert.

Can anyone point out where should I look for the source code of selenium webdriver where it gets the text and how does it do it?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/

Comment: @Faiz - I know that thing and thanks for the link. But I actually want someone to point out the exact location say a .cs file or .h file or .js file. Its a huge code and I loose track while searching for it. And actually, my issue got resolved, there was a fix provided by my development team which was related to MozRepl-XUL Runner and now it gets the popup text properly. Though it would be good if someone can provide some insight on how selenium gets the message text from alert or confirm?